# Error with file upload in jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jersey

I am creating an API for uploading files using jersey.

```
 @Path("/api")
 public class GreetingService {

     @POST
             @Path("/upload")
      @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
     //@Produces("text/plain")
     public String uploadFile(@FormParam("file") File file, @FormParam("file")    FormDataContentDisposition fcdsFile) {
      String fileLocation = "/files/" + fcdsFile.getFileName();
      //File destFile = new File(fileLocation);  

      return "1";
```

}
}

When I do 
    curl -v -X POST --form file=@rt.txt url
I get

```
       SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception
     java.lang.NullPointerException for this line    String fileLocation = "/files/" + fcdsFile.getFileName();
```

Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should make your call

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA) // same as "multipart/form-data"
//@Produces("text/plain")
public String uploadFile(
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
){
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: The topic-starter talked ab/ the another problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change second annotation from form param to

```
@FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fcdsFile
```